# Why don't I have a graph button in Neo4j Desktop?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have built my first graph from real data using Neo4j Browser version 4.0.3, server version 3.5.6 and am getting query results.

For example, this query returns 112 records:

```
MATCH (pls:PLS)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(pl:PL)
WITH pl, count(pls) AS num_pls
WHERE num_pls > 20
RETURN pl.id, pl.node_name, num_pls
```

However, I cannot visualize my results because there is no graph button in the left margin of the browser results pane -- only the "Table", "Text", and "Code" buttons.

I've been searching the doco and Googling, but nothing I've found mentions this issue.

Comment: Neo4j Desktop version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 2):

A query has to `RETURN` some nodes, relationships, and/or paths in order for the Browser to show a "Graph" visualization of them.

Your query is only returning a couple of properties and a calculated value.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam. I didn't realise it was as simple as `RETURN *`.